# How can I send the uploaded file (by filepond) with phpMailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer, filepond

I'm using filepond (https://pqina.nl/filepond/) to upload files on my server. 
I was able to use the php boilerplate (https://github.com/pqina/filepond-server-php) 
and was able to upload my file with filepond but was wondering how
to send it with phpMailer? How to combine this code (Rik's send.php) with phpMailer?

As I noticed this code below puts the file on the server. By the way I do not need to store it I would like only to reach it in the temp folder and send it. After it can be deleted...

```
<?php

// Comment if you don't want to allow posts from other domains
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

// Allow the following methods to access this file
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');

// Load the FilePond class
require_once('FilePond.class.php');

// Load our configuration for this server
require_once('config.php');

// Catch server exceptions and auto jump to 500 response code if caught
FilePond\catch_server_exceptions();
FilePond\route_form_post(ENTRY_FIELD, [
    'FILE_OBJECTS' => 'handle_file_post',
    'BASE64_ENCODED_FILE_OBJECTS' => 'handle_base64_encoded_file_post',
    'TRANSFER_IDS' => 'handle_transfer_ids_post'
]);

function handle_file_post($files) {

    // This is a very basic implementation of a classic PHP upload function, please properly
    // validate all submitted files before saving to disk or database, more information here
    // http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

    foreach($files as $file) {
        FilePond\move_file($file, UPLOAD_DIR);
    }
}

function handle_base64_encoded_file_post($files) {

    foreach ($files as $file) {

        // Suppress error messages, we'll assume these file objects are valid
        /* Expected format:
        {
            "id": "iuhv2cpsu",
            "name": "picture.jpg",
            "type": "image/jpeg",
            "size": 20636,
            "metadata" : {...}
            "data": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAA..."
        }
        */
        $file = @json_decode($file);

        // Skip files that failed to decode
        if (!is_object($file)) continue;

        // write file to disk
        FilePond\write_file(
            UPLOAD_DIR,
            base64_decode($file->data),
            FilePond\sanitize_filename($file->name)
        );
    }

}

function handle_transfer_ids_post($ids) {

    foreach ($ids as $id) {

        // create transfer wrapper around upload
        $transfer = FilePond\get_transfer(TRANSFER_DIR, $id);

        // transfer not found
        if (!$transfer) continue;

        // move files
        $files = $transfer->getFiles(defined('TRANSFER_PROCESSOR') ? TRANSFER_PROCESSOR : null);
        foreach($files as $file) {
            FilePond\move_file($file, UPLOAD_DIR);
        }

        // remove transfer directory
        FilePond\remove_transfer_directory(TRANSFER_DIR, $id);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is two separate operations:

- Fetch a file from a remote location
- Add it to an email as an attachment

The most straightforward way to do this with PHPMailer:

```php
$path = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'emailfile');
if (file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents('https://example.com/path/to/file.png'))) {
    $mail->addAttachment($path);
}
```

Note that PHPMailer explicitly avoids being an HTTP client itself; `addAttachment()` will not accept remote URLs, only local paths. Use a proper HTTP client class (like [guzzle](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle)) to fetch your data and store it in a file, then pass the pathname to PHPMailer.

Alternatively you can fetch the remote content as a binary string and pass it to PHPMailer via `addStringAttachment()`, which avoids writing to disk, though you should only do that for small items that you know will fit in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a file processor with `define('TRANSFER_PROCESSOR', 'send_phpmailer');` in config.php or in submit.php if you prefer.

```
function send_phpmailer($files,$meta){
  $mail = new PHPMailer();

  foreach($files as $file){
    $mail->addAttachment($file['tmp_name'], $file['name']);
  }

  // additional PHPMailer config
}
```